# Unity Circular Reference Annotating Objects

Tags: c#, unity-container

I'm trying to work on a legacy application (with source) to implement IoC using Unity.
The problem I am currently facing is that, Ive got 2 classes that is circular referencing each other.

Class A reference Class B
Class B reference Class A

I inject each of the dependency by using property setter with annotiation;

```
On class A:
[Dependency]
public IServiceA ServiceA { get; set; }


On class B:
[Dependency]
public IServiceB ServiceB { get; set; }
```

Unity will go into a circular referencing because of this.
Is there a way to go around (besides refactoring the methods inside) as these classes are legacy and I do not want to spend so much effort in changing the design of them?

Answer (score 1):

Unity will do this steps when you try to resolve A.

```
Create A
Look at Properties for A and create them
Found B will create B
Look at Properties for B and create them
Found A will Create A
```

You are stuck in a loop.

Your best option is to create C which A and B depend on.  However C does not depend on A or B.

Comment: Thanks David!, I already know the approach on this, just that the affort required to refactor the existing classes might be abit too big! (was hoping for a workaround) lol

Answer (score 0):

I agree that refactoring is the best practice, but you can achieve what you are after by changing one or both of the properties to be `Lazy<T>`.  Then Unity will not resolve the other instance until you *use* that property.

```
On class A:
[Dependency]
public Lazy<IServiceA> ServiceA { get; set; }


On class B:
[Dependency]
public Lazy<IServiceB> ServiceB { get; set; }
```

---

Or you could change their registration lifetimes so they reuse the same instances.  This may not work for you though if you do not want the same instances to be shared.  Maybe PerResolveLifetime would work?

1. Resolve A (Instantiate A)
2. Detects B dependency
3. Resolve B (Instantiate B)
4. Detects A dependency
5. Resolve A (Reuse instance A due to lifetime and completes recursion)

Example:

```
container.RegisterType<A>(new PerResolveLifetimeManager());
```

Comment: I've since fixed the problem by refactoring, before that I've also tried using PerResolveLifeTime which also works, I was unable to use Lazy<T> because its for a project that works on .NET 3.5 !

Answer (score 0):

This is a frustrating limitation of Unity indeed. However, there is a 2-pass solution:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnityTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Cure_For_UnityNotBeingVerySmartAtBindingCircularDependentProperties()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterType<ISharedResource, SharedResource>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

        container.RegisterType<ICycleA, CycleA>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), new InjectionProperty("SharedResource"));
        container.RegisterType<ICycleB, CycleB>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), new InjectionProperty("SharedResource"));

        var a = container.Resolve<ICycleA>();
        var b = container.Resolve<ICycleB>();

        container.RegisterType<ICycleA, CycleA>("buildup", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<ICycleB, CycleB>("buildup", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

        container.BuildUp(a, "buildup");
        container.BuildUp(b, "buildup");

        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(a, typeof(CycleA));
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(a.Dependency, typeof(CycleB));
        Assert.AreSame(a, a.Dependency.Dependency);
    }
}

internal interface ISharedResource { }

class SharedResource : ISharedResource { }

class CycleB : ICycleB
{
    [Dependency]public ISharedResource SharedResource { get; set; }
    [Dependency]public ICycleA Dependency { get; set; }
}

class CycleA : ICycleA
{
    [Dependency]public ISharedResource SharedResource { get; set; }
    [Dependency]public ICycleB Dependency { get; set; }
}
interface ICycleB
{
    [Dependency]ISharedResource SharedResource { get; set; }
    [Dependency]ICycleA Dependency { get; set; }
}
interface ICycleA
{
    [Dependency]ISharedResource SharedResource { get; set; }
    [Dependency]ICycleB Dependency { get; set; }
}
```

It takes advantage of the InjectionProperty overload which tells Unity to only wire up the specified Dependencies.

If your classes have a shared resource (e.g Logging service), register this Dependency on the 1st pass, with the final BuildUp pass connecting all the classes together.

It does require a call to Resolve and BuildUp on all classes, a little awkward but can be automated with UnityContainer extensions fairly easily.

This should be addressed by Microsoft as it is a fairly standard use case.